Can I add my own function in nn.Sequential?
I'm a beginner in machine learning. Recently, I'm trying to use CGAN for image generation and lebelling.
Currently, I'm manually doing circular padding in convolution operation as following.
def pad_dim(x, n=1):
    x = torch.cat((x[:,:,:,-n:], x, x[:,:,:,:n]), axis=-1)
    x = torch.cat((x[:,:,-n:,:], x, x[:,:,:n,:]), axis=-2)
    return x
class pad_dim_x(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        #batch_size = x.shape[0]
        return pad_dim(x, n=1)
...
class Generator(nn.Module):
...
            self.main = nn.Sequential(
                pad_dim_x(),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 0, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
                nn.ReLU(True),
                ...)
...

Some codes are omitted since they are common.
My final goal is to integrate a custom function into nn.Sequential. Is my current approach correct?

Yes your current approach seems correct. Create a custom class that inherits from nn.Module, make it do whatever you want in forward and then plug it in an nn.Sequential, that should work. Is there something specific you are struggling with ? By the way, in case you missed it, there is a torch.nn.functional.pad function to do the padding you want, it can do circular padding

@trialNerror, thanks for your quick reply. It did work. But I'm wondering the class pad_dim_x is outside the class Generator, will it interfere the backpropagation computation?

no it should not, the computational graph used for backprop is stored within the tensors, no the modules. However if you want to create a custom module with internal parameters that you want to train / save / load when you train your generator class, then you need to use nn.Parameter like explained in pytorch tutorial. But your pad_dim_x class has no parameters, therefore no problem
